# How to access the script from inactive gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When i try to access the Player script from my Save and Load Script. it always say "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I know the cause of it is the GameObject is inactive.

```
public Player player;

void Start()
{
  player = GetComponent<Player>().
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes from the tiny bit of code and information you have that would be the issue. Unity's start function will only get called when the object is turned active. I would suggest you move this sort of initialization into its own function.

Also you could do something like lazy initializating property were you assign the reference when you need it :

```
private Player m_Player;
public Player player 
{
    get 
    {
        if (m_Player == null)
        {
            m_Player = GetComponent<Player>();
        }

        return m_Player;
    }
}
```

In this example **player** is now a property which you call all the same as before, but when you do there's a check if the variable m_Player is null which will then assign it.